# El símbolo de puntuación mágico

Tags: bug

Dejo aquí un bug que he encontrado. Sé que no es gran cosa, pero me llamó la atención cuando lo vi.

He escrito [un comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2526/qu%C3%A9-tipos-de-nested-browsing-context-existen/#comment3941_2596) que incluye una URL:

> A mí me funcionan las dos usando "https://jsfiddle.net". No sé si será alguna configuración de mi navegador

Pero cuando le doy a guardar el comentario, aparece por parte de magia un punto y coma que yo no he escrito justo después de la URL:

> A mí me funcionan las dos usando "jsfiddle.net";. No sé si será alguna configuración de mi navegador

Parece que cuando se procesan los comentarios y se transforman las URLs en enlaces, se añade un punto y coma por arte de magia, pero sólo si el enlace va entre comillas (en cuyo caso, la comilla de cierre se convierte en parte del enlace también y lo rompe).

Comment: Hola me pasa con los link que coloco entre comillas, ejemplo:

sin comillas:  http://juank.io
con comillas:  "http://juank.io"

Comment: quizá deberías reportarlo en "http://meta.stackexchange.com" )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buscando en meta StackOverflow, he encontrado una [pregunta similar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307111/delimited-uris-in-comments-cause-broken-links) (pero en ese caso ocurre con los caracteres `<` y `>`).

Según un [comentario de Chris Jester-Young](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307111/delimited-uris-in-comments-cause-broken-links#comment252846_307111), la causa del error es el script utilizado para parsear los comentarios (llamado MarkdowMini) que es diferente al usado para procesar los posts. Parece que es un bug de MarkdownMini.